# Make mutt send plain text only - no html

Tags: mutt

**--- Edit ---**

This was due to a setting in sendgrid who we use to relay our email, not mutt.

---

I have a report that I will run daily and want to email the results using mutt.  I put the report in a text file, then use

`mutt me@myaddress.co.uk -s "My report"  < emailbody.txt`

The resulting email contains a section with

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Disposition: inline

 - staging_tts_db - Schema Change found

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

4301c4301
< ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=918489 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
---
> ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=918488 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and the message is plain text and correctly formatted, followed by a section with

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html><body>
<pre>- staging_tts_db - Schema Change found</pre>
<p>------------------------------------------------------------------------=
--------</p>
<h3>4301c4301 &lt; ) ENGINE=3DMyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3D918489 DEFAULT CHARSE=
T=3Dlatin1;</h3>
<blockquote><p>) ENGINE=3DMyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3D918488 DEFAULT CHARSET=3D=
latin1;</p></blockquote>
```

and the formatting is all over the place. My email glient (gmail) is picking up the html version to display

I want to only generate the plain text  version of the email. I have tried passing a header as part of the email body, but that's just added as text within the message.

I had it working correctly using sendmail, but as I want to include an attachment, I've switched to using mutt.

I'm using mutt 1.5.21 on Debian wheezy

Comment: What does you `.muttrc` file look like?

Comment: I haven't got a user-specific `.muttrc`. Everything else is out-of-the box

Comment: AFAIK, `mutt` does not implement a facility to automatically convert plan text messages into HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use postfix and sendgrid to deliver the emails from our systems.

`sendmail` was sending the email directly (not via postfix/sendgrid), so wasn't adding the html part of the email.

Sendgrid has a setting (on by default) that adds a html version of the email as well.

`mutt` was sending emails via postfix/sendgrid and was getting the html added. After changing the setting (*Settings ... Plain Content ... Convert your plain text emails to HTML ... Turn on if you don't want to convert your plain text email to HTML*) it is working as expected.